# Running tox under debugger

Tags: debugging, tox

I am a new volunteer working on an open source project which uses tox for automated testing. As a way of learning, I am interested in seeing how tox calls the functions in the API - what arguments it passes to them, for example. Is there a way to see how it calls the functions being tested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tox` does not execute tests directly, but usually drives a testrunner, e.g. `pytest` or others.

e.g. from one of my project's `tox.ini`

```
[testenv]
description = run the tests with pytest
extras = test
commands = pytest {posargs}
```

You could set a breakpoint via `breakpoint()` (on Python 3.7 or newer) or via `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` in e.g.
https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/blob/86a0383c0617ff1d1ea47a526211bedc415c9d95/src/tox/session/commands/run/sequential.py#L67-L76
and step through the process.

Though, this should not be necessary if you just want to maintain an open source project.

If you have further questions, we have a pretty decent documentation at https://tox.wiki/en/latest/ and also a friendly chat at https://discord.gg/tox